# Some results disappear after GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table of Employment and I select everyone whose ID is repeated,

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
        FROM Employment Emp 
        JOIN Employee e
        ON e.emp_id = Emp.emp_id
        JOIN Department d 
        ON Emp.dept_id = d.dept_id
        GROUP BY e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
        HAVING count(Emp.emp_id) > 1
```

[image: having this result]

But after I use d.name (department name) in SELECT and GROUP BY some employees disappear.

```
    SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, d.name
        FROM Employment Emp 
        JOIN Employee e
        ON e.emp_id = Emp.emp_id
        JOIN Department d 
        ON Emp.dept_id = d.dept_id
        GROUP BY e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name,d.name
        HAVING count(Emp.emp_id) > 1
```

[image: Result after adding d.name]

**I want to get all employee departments who are in first table.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function instead:

```
SELECT ed.*
FROM (SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, d.name,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name) as cnt
      FROM Employment Emp JOIN
           Employee e
           ON e.emp_id = Emp.emp_id JOIN
           Department d 
           ON Emp.dept_id = d.dept_id
     ) ed
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY ed.emp_id, ed.first_name, ed.last_name;
```

Comment: ORDER BY doesn't work, it says : "The multi-part identifier e.emp_id not found"

Comment: @postoffice . . . I changed the alias for the subquery to `ed`.

Answer (score 0):

Your two queries ask different questions. The second `count()` is more granulated  (+ by `department.name`) and looks like no one of "disappeard" persons is employed at the same department twice or more.